# Dynamic field content as Row Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following dataset on a sql database

```
 ----------------------------------
|  ID   | NAME    | AGE  | STATUS |
-----------------------------------
| 1ASDF | Brenda  | 21   | Single |
-----------------------------------
| 2FDSH | Ging    | 24   | Married|
-----------------------------------
| 3SDFD | Judie   | 18   | Widow  |
-----------------------------------
| 4GWWX | Sophie  | 21   | Married|
-----------------------------------
| 5JDSI | Mylene  | 24   | Singe  |
-----------------------------------
```

I want to query that dataset so that i can have this structure in my result

```
--------------------------------------
|  AGE  | SINGLE  | MARRIED  | WIDOW |
--------------------------------------
| 21    | 1        | 1       | 0     |
--------------------------------------
| 24    | 1        | 1       | 0     |
--------------------------------------
| 18    | 0        | 0       | 1     |
--------------------------------------
```

And the status column can be dynamic so there will be more columns to come.
Is this possible?

Comment: Conceptually, you need a pivot over status column, grouping by age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, you can use the `PIVOT` table operator like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Age, Name, Status FROM tablename 
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Name)
  FOR Status IN(Single, Married, Widow)
) AS p;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a0d2/3)

---

To do it dynamically you have to use dynamic sql like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(status)
                      FROM tablename
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = '
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Age, Name, Status FROM tablename 
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Name)
  FOR Status IN( ' +@cols + ')
) AS p;';


execute(@query);
```

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a0d2/4)

Comment: Tnx Mahmoud! I've tested both of your answers but the only the first query was running fine. It was later that i decided to test those queries using mssql server management studio and both perfectly worked. I was using navicat then. I'm wondering what was wrong with navicat. Anyways this helped me a lot. Kudos!